# Gandora The Dragon Of Destruction and Union Monsters

Tags: yu-gi-oh

If my opponent is using a monster that is equipped with a union, and I use Gandora The Dragon Of Destruction's field clearing effect against that monster equiped with a union,  does the union card get destroyed, or both of the monster cards being affected by Gandora's effect?

Answer (score 2):

Both the of the cards would be destroyed, also including the rest of the field, but the destroyed monsters can still use their effects.